# Can I run arcgis javascript code in Arcgis Desktop

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

Basically, what I am looking for is, I want to learn Arcgis javascript api. And I have Arcgis Desktop 10.3 Trial version installed on my pc. I have heard that javascript can be run only in Arcgis Server based web application. So is there any possibility to run this javascript code in Arcgis Desktop? If not, suggest me ideas on how to get a Arcgis Server Trial for practicing javascript api.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use ArcGIS Desktop to run Javascript api app. It is a web based sdk. You can simple run it on any browser. The main things is you would need ArcGIS Server Services to display data on the map.

To learn you dont need to have a server on your local, you can use arcgis online services. You can find more details on their website.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/

Answer (score 0):

AS T Kambi, said you don't need server to start learning ArcGIS API for JavaScript. If you have a REST endpoint you can use that or peruse AGOL for a layer.

If you're really ambitious the API will also consume OGC Web Map Services, so you could create a Geoserver and publish your data as a WMS layer.

Check out the esri\layers section of the [API Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WMSLayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Explicit, you can't run javascript on arcgis desktop, ArcGis Javascript Api only need Api Rest y you can get it trough of examples for ArcGis.
Too other option mores easy is Create account developer in ArcGis under this link 
https://developers.arcgis.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use ArcGIS Desktop to run Javascript app. It is a web based SDK. You can simple run it on any browser. Also if your doesn't  have access to internet you can use ArcGis SDK
for more information click below link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3sB1I8CB80

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. There is a difference between the javascript api
and desktop api.